# Active class versus passive class

Tags: uml, specifications, class-diagram

**In UML specification superstructure 2.5(still Beta, page 203)**

> A Class may be designated by setting isActive to true as active (i.e.,
>   each of its instances is an active object). When isActive is false the
>   Class is passive (i.e., each of its instances executes within the
>   context of some other object).

- I wonder if there is a simple example illustrates the differences in applying each one of them?
- And elaborate this concept a bit?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By definition,

> **Active Objects**
>   In UML, active classes, *and therefore active objects*,
>   exist in their own thread of operations and have their own address
>   space. If execution, or code activity, is thought of in terms of flow,
>   active objects can start or control that flow. Active objects, *in
>   other words, are sequential and do something: modify variables, change
>   program behavior, and so on.* In UML, active classes and objects are
>   distinguished by having a thicker border than passive objects.
>
> **Passive objects** in UML do not generally have the
>   ability to modify or begin the flow of execution, because they must
>   wait for another object to call them. Instead, *passive objects are
>   generally used to store information*, and in many cases this
>   information may be shared between multiple other objects. **This may
>   allow passive objects to be accessed concurrently, not sequentially.**
>   To make sure that the data contained inside has a high integrity, UML
>   allows for passive objects to insist that they be accessed
>   sequentially; if two threads attempt to call the same sequential
>   passive object, that object can delay the second thread until the
>   first has finished with it.

A helpful example could be found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56617/Applied-Long-Running-Active-Object-Pattern)